# CFSCRIPT - How can I change the reference to shorten the name?

Tags: coldfusion

I do a for loop in CFSCRIPT. I am looping through a query and dropping the fields into a table cell via a UDF (that's what the wrapCell() is).

```
for(i = 1; i lte GetUsers.RecordCount; i++) {
Cells = Cells & wrapCell("#GetUsers.FirstName[i]# #GetUsers.LastName[i]#");
Cells = Cells & wrapCell(lcase(GetUsers.Email[i]));
Cells = Cells & wrapCell(getYesNo(GetUsers.Active[i]));
writeOutput(wrapRow(Cells));
}
```

Each time I need to reference a field I have to write this:

```
GetUsers.FirstName[i]
GetUsers.LastName[i]
GetUsers.Email[i]
GetUsers.Active[i]
```

Id' really like to be able to reference this stuff as like this:

```
FirstName
LastName
Email
Active
```

Is there a way to change the reference before the output row so that it takes up less space?  For example, can I do something like this:

```
ThisRow = GetUsersStructure.RowInfo[i];
FirstName
LastName
Email
Active
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any native method that would allow you to do this when using `<cfscript>`, but you could create another convenience method to do it. For example

```
public struct function getByRow( query q, numeric index ){
  return {
       firstname = q.firstname[index],
       lastname = q.lastname[index],
       email = q.email[index],
       active = q.active[index]
  }; 

}
```

You could even take it another step further and have the method loop through `q.columnlist` to make it generic for re-use.

Answer (score 1):

You can. It'll add overhead.

Convert your row or whole query to a struct.
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/149-Ask-Ben-Converting-A-Query-To-A-Struct.htm

Then throw the results into the local scope.

```
StructAppend( local , QueryToStruct( GetUsers, i ) );
```

If you're on CF9/railo, then you can access them simply by column name. (I haven't tested this.)

Comment: Who is this Ben Nadel guy? Doesn't he have anything to do but to write helpful tutorials?  Yeah, I think this is exaclty what I was looking for.  I'll implement it and let you know. Thanks!